# Assign progressive ID based on two criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two columns about the IDs of participants in my study. The column `ID` contains progressive order of numbers as the subjects were all distinct people. The second column `new_ID` contains the information about which IDs correspond to the same person. Unfortunately they are not in the progressive order.

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)
new_ID <- c(8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)

data.frame(ID, new_ID)

#   ID  new_ID
#1   1       8
#2   1       8
#3   1       8
#4   1       8
#5   2      10
#6   2      10
#7   2      10
#8   2      10
#9   2      10
#10  2      10
#11  3       8
#12  3       8
#13  3       8
#14  3       8
#15  3       8
#16  4       4
#17  4       4
#18  4       4
#19  4       4
#20  4       4
#21  4       4
#22  5       5
#23  5       5
#24  5       5
#25  5       5
#26  6      10
#27  6      10
#28  6      10
#29  6      10
#30  6      10
#31  6      10
#32  6      10
```

I reported below what I would like to achieve, i.e. assigning the new ID (`final_ID`) based on the information in the two first columns. Any helps will be appreciated (best if using `dplyr`)!

```
#   ID new_ID ID_final
#1   1      8        1
#2   1      8        1
#3   1      8        1
#4   1      8        1
#5   2     10        2
#6   2     10        2
#7   2     10        2
#8   2     10        2
#9   2     10        2
#10  2     10        2
#11  3      8        1
#12  3      8        1
#13  3      8        1
#14  3      8        1
#15  3      8        1
#16  4      4        4
#17  4      4        4
#18  4      4        4
#19  4      4        4
#20  4      4        4
#21  4      4        4
#22  5      5        5
#23  5      5        5
#24  5      5        5
#25  5      5        5
#26  6     10        2
#27  6     10        2
#28  6     10        2
#29  6     10        2
#30  6     10        2
#31  6     10        2
#32  6     10        2
```

Comment: @H1 You are right! The syntax was correct, but the copied table was wrong. I have just edited it. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution as well.

EDIT: added a `dplyr` solution too at the request of the OP.

```r
library(data.table)
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)
new_ID <- c(8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)

d <- data.table(ID, new_ID)
d[, ID_final := min(.SD[,ID]), new_ID]
d
#>     ID new_ID ID_final
#>  1:  1      8        1
#>  2:  1      8        1
#>  3:  1      8        1
#>  4:  1      8        1
#>  5:  2     10        2
#>  6:  2     10        2
#>  7:  2     10        2
#>  8:  2     10        2
#>  9:  2     10        2
#> 10:  2     10        2
#> 11:  3      8        1
#> 12:  3      8        1
#> 13:  3      8        1
#> 14:  3      8        1
#> 15:  3      8        1
#> 16:  4      4        4
#> 17:  4      4        4
#> 18:  4      4        4
#> 19:  4      4        4
#> 20:  4      4        4
#> 21:  4      4        4
#> 22:  5      5        5
#> 23:  5      5        5
#> 24:  5      5        5
#> 25:  5      5        5
#> 26:  6     10        2
#> 27:  6     10        2
#> 28:  6     10        2
#> 29:  6     10        2
#> 30:  6     10        2
#> 31:  6     10        2
#> 32:  6     10        2
#>     ID new_ID ID_final

library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID, new_ID)
df <- df %>% group_by(new_ID)  %>%
  mutate(ID_final = min(ID))
df
#> # A tibble: 32 x 3
#> # Groups:   new_ID [4]
#>       ID new_ID ID_final
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     1      8        1
#>  2     1      8        1
#>  3     1      8        1
#>  4     1      8        1
#>  5     2     10        2
#>  6     2     10        2
#>  7     2     10        2
#>  8     2     10        2
#>  9     2     10        2
#> 10     2     10        2
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is a great solution! Do you happen to know how to perform a similar operation with `dplyr`? I use that package to code and I would like to be consistent. Also, it wouldn't be feasible to implement this chunk of code in my current data set due to the presence of many other variables and previous code. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Sure thing, it's done. Though I'm not a usual `tidyverse` user so I don't know if this would be the best way in that paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is find the correct ID for each new_ID, and then join to that mapping.

```
final_id_map <- df %>% group_by(new_ID) %>% summarise(ID_final=min(ID))
> final_id_map
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  new_ID ID_final
   <dbl>    <dbl>
1      4        4
2      5        5
3      8        1
4     10        2
```

Then you can just do a

```
df %>% join(final_id_map)
```

to produce the desired output.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Unfortunately, I need to sort the student from to 1 to n beginning from the top of my data set. They cannot be in a different order in that there is a criteria based on which they were sorted (beginning of an intervention). Let me know if you happen to know a different solution, but I really appreciated you taking the time for me.